# Error with TwilioRestClient in Python 2.7

Tags: python, twilio

I recently installed Twilio module and I am using Python 2.7

***Credentials.py -->***

```
account_sid = "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

auth_token = "978XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

my_phone = "+XXXXXXXXXXXX"

my_twilio = "+XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

***message.py ----->***

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

from credentials import account_sid, auth_token, my_phone, my_twilio

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = 'Hello Sarthak, How are you?'

final_message = client.messages.create(to=my_phone, from_=my_twilio, 
body=message)
```

When I try to run this, I am getting this error :-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
From twilio.rest import Client
```

TwilioRestClient is deprecated. You have to import Client instead. Make sure you are using Python 3 too.

Comment: When I try to import Client, it says undefined reference means it’s not able to locate Client inside twilio.rest, I am using python 2.7, do I need to use 3.x. ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Twilio support of older versions, but that sounds like a good idea. Try running it inside a Python 3 environment.